# Error: "pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

Tags: errors, compiling

I have output a Latex file from Wolfram Mathematica using the first very simple example shown at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/TeX.html
I then tried to compile it with TexMaker 4.5 on a Macbook Version 10.9.4 (Mavericks). I couldn't get the pdf, because of error:

```
 "pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Anybody knows why? The full text is:

```
  %% AMS-LaTeX Created with the Wolfram Language for Students - Personal Use 
  Only : www.wolfram.com

 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}

\newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{{}}

\newcounter{mathematicapage}
\begin{document}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\pmb{\text{ExportString}[\text{Nest}
[1+1/\#\&,x,5],\text{{``}TeX{''}}]}\)
\end{doublespace}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\text{$\%\%$ AMS-LaTeX Created with the Wolfram Language for 
Students - Personal Use Only : www.wolfram.com$\backslash $n$\backslash 
$n$\backslash
\backslash $documentclass$\{$article$\}\backslash $n$\backslash \backslash 
$usepackage$\{$amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace$\}\backslash $n$\backslash
$n$\backslash \backslash $newcommand$\{\backslash \backslash $mathsym$\}$[1]$\
{\{\}\}\backslash $n$\backslash \backslash $newcommand$\{\backslash
\backslash $unicode$\}$[1]$\{\{\}\}\backslash $n$\backslash $n$\backslash 
\backslash $newcounter$\{$mathematicapage$\}\backslash $n$\backslash 
\backslash
$begin$\{$document$\}\backslash $n$\backslash $n$\backslash \backslash 
$[1+$\backslash \backslash $frac$\{$1$\}\{$1+$\backslash \backslash $frac$\
{$1$\}\{$1+$\backslash
\backslash $frac$\{$1$\}\{$1+$\backslash \backslash $frac$\{$1$\}\
{$1+$\backslash \backslash $frac$\{$1$\}\{$x$\}\}\}\}\}\backslash \backslash 
$]$\backslash
$n$\backslash $n$\backslash \backslash $end$\{$document$\}\backslash $n}\)
\end{doublespace}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Comment out the second line.

Comment: have you installed a TeX system? TeXMaker is just an editor it needs tex to process the document (miktex or texlive distributions)

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't installed the compiler

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP didn't have the compiler installed.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your code has some issues:

1. You have to comment out the second line (`% Only :`).
2. There are many linebreaks after a `\`. This causes the braces (`{`) to be unescaped.
3. It is very bad style. All of the text goes on one line and there's a real misuse of math mode. Best thing to do: Look at the source code, discard that one and rewrite the content from scratch.

I do not know Mathematica well enough to judge its LaTeX capabilities, but this is definitely a bad sign.

Code:

```
%% AMS-LaTeX Created with the Wolfram Language for Students - Personal Use 
%  Only : www.wolfram.com
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}

\newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{{}}

\newcounter{mathematicapage}
\begin{document}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\pmb{\text{ExportString}[\text{Nest}
[1+1/\#\&,x,5],\text{{``}TeX{''}}]}\)
\end{doublespace}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\text{$\%\%$ AMS-LaTeX Created with the Wolfram Language for Students - Personal Use Only : www.wolfram.com$\backslash $n$\backslash 
$n$\backslash \backslash $documentclass$\{$article$\}\backslash $n$\backslash \backslash $usepackage$\{$amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace$\}\backslash $n$\backslash $n$\backslash \backslash $newcommand$\{\backslash \backslash $mathsym$\}$[1]$
\{\{\}\}\backslash $n$\backslash \backslash $newcommand$\{\backslash
\backslash $unicode$\}$[1]$\{\{\}\}\backslash $n$\backslash $n$\backslash 
\backslash $newcounter$\{$mathematicapage$\}\backslash $n$\backslash 
\backslash
$begin$\{$document$\}\backslash $n$\backslash $n$\backslash \backslash 
$[1+$\backslash \backslash $frac$\{$1$\}\{$1+$\backslash \backslash $frac$
\{$1$\}\{$1+$\backslash
\backslash $frac$\{$1$\}\{$1+$\backslash \backslash $frac$\{$1$\}
\{$1+$\backslash \backslash $frac$\{$1$\}\{$x$\}\}\}\}\}\backslash \backslash 
$]$\backslash $n$\backslash $n$\backslash \backslash $end$\{$document$\}\backslash $n}\)
\end{doublespace}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I just copied your code and got the same error

Comment: @AndreaG Well, I get no errors anymore. Could you please be more specific what error?

Comment: Error : could not start the command : "pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "ass".tex; It is weird: I am compiling fine another latex file I have, but not yours corrected.

Comment: @AndreaG Could you please open the command line, compile it in your command-line with `pdflatex ass.tex` (if the filename is right) and then post the output?

Comment: I am new to the language: what do you mean more precisely with "open the command line"? Do you mean the terminal? Could you explain me or give me instructions on how to do that?

Comment: @AndreaG Yes, I mean the terminal. Under Linux: Use your file browser and search in the menus for open in terminal. Under Windows: Shift-rightclick into the folder and choose open in terminal. Under Mac: Idk. Then you should also be in the right folder and just type the command from above.

Comment: I think I got `-bash: pdflatex: command not found`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58353/discussion-between-texnician-and-andrea-g).